# First whitespace doesn't trigger the onEditorChange function in react JS TinyMCE version 6.8.2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce, whitespace, tinymce-6

I've asked the same question on tinymce github too and seems like no one cares.
Does anyone have any idea why the first whitespace we enter to the editor is not recognized by the tinymce editor?
I'm self hosting tinymce 6.8.2 in my react project.
When I try to console the html text of the editor, it doesn't show the first whitespace. But when I add two whitespaces it shows two &nbsp's, It works well with every other characters, but it doesn't work with first whitespace. I'll provide the code sandbox link where I tested if this issue is common or not, I've consoled the html in it, Can anyone help? Thank you in advance.
Code Sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/tinymce-react-demo-forked-t38l25?file=%2Fsrc%2FDocumentEditor.jsx